# Correctness of "... if verb-with-ed ..." form

Tags: past-participles

Is this sentence correct?

> The *A* could be efficiently substituted if first converted to a *B*.

It's a technical text; the meaning is: there is a chemical compound bearing substituent *A*, *A* can be converted into another substituent *B*, and only after that *B* can be substituted completely with something else. I have words/chars count limit here, so the phrase should be as concise as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: What are A and B? We need to know whether they are countable nouns.

Answer (score 1):

> The A could be efficiently substituted if first converted to a B.

If A can be substituted **only** after it has been converted to B, the question of efficiency would not arise; it is a matter of possibility.  I suggest the following:

The A could be substituted only after it is first converted to a B.